# I have a fibre glass roofing on my trailer and water accumulate near roof vent. It cause leakage

Tags: roof, waterproofing, vent

[image][image]I have a fibre glass roofing, and water accumulate near ventilator. It makes it way and cause leakage. I need to make some slide on that Groove so water won't stay there. I don't want to redo roofing as it will cost me alot. I need a quick solution to make a slide. To prevent leakage, I have already used sealent, filler etc near vent area. But now I am thinking only solution is to make a slide there.

Comment: Photos or diagrams of the problem area would help a lot.

Comment: If you will post a picture of the area it will better provide the community with an understanding of your issue and be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: thanks for the pic...but we were wanting one of the outside where the rain actually falls.

Comment: I have added another pic

Comment: What does "make a slide" mean?

Comment: As per my understanding the roofing is installed in opposite direction and this results in accumulation of water in the grooves. I know I have to redo the roofing but for temporary solution to avoid water gathering in the grooves, I am thinking to make a slide near vent area so water won't gather. Slide means either to add glue and then form at the top and sealing it with good quality sealent. I want to change direction of water from leakage area for a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the sheet roofing thing in the past and this looks like a do-over to me.

Sheet roofing is reliant on the slopes shedding water in down-hill to keep the rain out.

If you disturb the slopes or the facets of the roof you have to maintain the sloped path  so that the roof stays rainproof.  I cant see what's going on inside that mess, so my first step put be disassembling it until I can see what's going on.

In general the flashing should be under the sheeting on the upper side and below it on the lower side.